# Volley for downloading json, images... and also audio?

Tags: android, android-volley

I´ve been reading the questions that are in StackOverFlow about Volley and I´m still unsure if the approach that I have in mind of how to use it, is correct or not.

My usecase is the following: I first download an index (text file) that contains the set of URLs from the files that I have to download, then I read it and put its content in a list (in the following code; "urls"). Lastly, my idea is to do something like this:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
        String url = urls[i];
        final int p = i;

        if (urls[i].contains("json")) {

            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            // Save the data or whatever
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                         @Override
                         public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                         // Handle the error
                         }
                    }
            );
            queue.add(jsObjRequest);
        } else if (urls[i].contains("png") || urls[i].contains("jpeg")) {
                int memClass = ((ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                        .getMemoryClass();
                // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
                int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 8;
                ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(queue, new BitmapLruCache(cacheSize));

                imageLoader.get(urls[p],
                        ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageDisplay,
                                R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                                R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                );
        } else {
            // The file is not a json or an image
            // What should I do?
        }
    }
```

So basically my questions are:

1.- Is it a good idea to have this kind of separation depending on the kind of request that you are going to make? Is there a better/cleaner way? In the examples that I´ve reading, they always cover just one scenario (either json, string or image download) and I´m unsure how to mix them.

2.- For the audio and video files that I would need to download from my index, considering that Volley is not meant for large downloads, should I just use an AsyncTask and OKHttp and execute it within that last "else"?

Any input about Volley will be appreciated.